# Mesos webUI display only the recently connected slave

Tags: mesos, master-slave, webui

I am setting up a mesos cluster for demonstration purpose. My setup is one master and two slaves. All machines are running ubuntu 14.04 LTS and on same local network. I am starting mesos master with the command as per the [documentation](http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/).

```
./mesos-master.sh --ip=192.168.65.27 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos
```

I can start and connect slave running on another machine to the master with

```
./mesos-slave.sh --master=192.168.65.27:5050
```

But whenever I try to connect one more slave to the same master, only the recently connected slave get listed under the webUI of mesos `http://192.168.65.24:5050/#/slaves`. I checked the terminal outputs. For one slave it goes on as follows.

```
I0107 11:31:39.346242  6742 slave.cpp:3053] Current usage 5.71%. Max allowed age:     
5.900004310159479days
I0107 11:32:39.349727  6744 slave.cpp:3053] Current usage 5.71%. Max allowed age:   
5.900000961729503days
I0107 11:33:39.355268  6740 slave.cpp:3053] Current usage 5.71%. Max allowed age:  
5.900000256796875days
I0107 11:34:39.355785  6744 slave.cpp:3053] Current usage 5.71%. Max allowed age: 
5.900000080563727days
I0107 11:35:39.376319  6742 slave.cpp:3053] Current usage 5.71%. Max allowed age: 
5.900009538409780days
```

and for the other its as given below

```
I0106 11:34:34.815814  6238 slave.cpp:3053] Current usage 40.74%. Max allowed age: 
3.448325928286030days
I0106 11:35:34.816684  6238 slave.cpp:3053] Current usage 40.74%. Max allowed age: 
3.448326110500035days
I0106 11:36:34.821465  6244 slave.cpp:3053] Current usage 40.74%. Max allowed age:   
3.448323923931886days
I0106 11:37:34.822031  6243 slave.cpp:3053] Current usage 40.74%. Max allowed age: 
3.448324106145903days
I0106 11:38:34.846472  6243 slave.cpp:3053] Current usage 40.74%. Max allowed age: 
3.448324835001956days
I0106 11:39:34.889264  6243 slave.cpp:3053] Current usage 40.74%. Max allowed age: 
3.448322101791771days
```

terminal ouput of mesos master is given below

```
I0107 15:12:28.482170  6412 master.cpp:2781] Removing old disconnected slave 20150107- 
150547-406956224-5050-6393-31 at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave2-ThinkCentre- 
Edge72)  because a registration attempt is being made from slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051
I0107 15:12:28.482221  6412 master.cpp:4218] Removing slave 20150107-150547-406956224-
5050-6393-31 at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave2-ThinkCentre-Edge72)
I0107 15:12:28.482307  6414 hierarchical_allocator_process.hpp:467] Removed slave 
20150107-150547-406956224-5050-6393-31
I0107 15:12:28.482364  6412 master.cpp:2811] Registering slave at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 
(mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72) with id 20150107-150547-406956224-5050-6393-32
I0107 15:12:28.482379  6414 registrar.cpp:422] Attempting to update the 'registry'
I0107 15:12:28.483706  6413 log.cpp:680] Attempting to append 344 bytes to the log
I0107 15:12:28.483772  6413 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write APPEND 
action at position 847
I0107 15:12:28.484074  6413 replica.cpp:508] Replica received write request for position  
847
I0107 15:12:28.537632  6413 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (364 bytes) to leveldb 
took 53.520241ms
I0107 15:12:28.537683  6413 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 847
I0107 15:12:28.537832  6413 replica.cpp:655] Replica received learned notice for position 
847
I0107 15:12:28.579407  6413 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (366 bytes) to leveldb 
took 41.551104ms
I0107 15:12:28.579454  6413 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 847
I0107 15:12:28.579471  6413 replica.cpp:661] Replica learned APPEND action at position   
847
I0107 15:12:28.579779  6413 registrar.cpp:479] Successfully updated 'registry'
I0107 15:12:28.579825  6409 log.cpp:699] Attempting to truncate the log to 847
I0107 15:12:28.579876  6413 registrar.cpp:422] Attempting to update the 'registry'
I0107 15:12:28.579929  6414 master.cpp:4321] Removed slave 20150107-150547-406956224-
5050-6393-31 (mesos_slave2-ThinkCentre-Edge72)
I0107 15:12:28.580001  6412 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write TRUNCATE 
action at position 848
I0107 15:12:28.580216  6412 replica.cpp:508] Replica received write request for position 
848
I0107 15:12:28.621160  6412 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (18 bytes) to leveldb took 
40.912992ms
I0107 15:12:28.621215  6412 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 848
I0107 15:12:28.621426  6413 replica.cpp:655] Replica received learned notice for position 
848
I0107 15:12:28.662858  6413 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (20 bytes) to leveldb took 
41.418688ms
I0107 15:12:28.662943  6413 leveldb.cpp:401] Deleting ~2 keys from leveldb took 32165ns
I0107 15:12:28.662963  6413 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 848
I0107 15:12:28.662976  6413 replica.cpp:661] Replica learned TRUNCATE action at position 
848
I0107 15:12:28.663244  6409 log.cpp:680] Attempting to append 550 bytes to the log
I0107 15:12:28.663331  6408 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write APPEND 
action at position 849
I0107 15:12:28.663539  6409 replica.cpp:508] Replica received write request for position 
849
I0107 15:12:28.704601  6409 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (570 bytes) to leveldb 
took 41.040042ms
I0107 15:12:28.704654  6409 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 849
I0107 15:12:28.704839  6410 replica.cpp:655] Replica received learned notice for position 
849
I0107 15:12:28.746300  6410 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (572 bytes) to leveldb 
took 41.427841ms
I0107 15:12:28.746354  6410 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 849
I0107 15:12:28.746371  6410 replica.cpp:661] Replica learned APPEND action at position 
849
I0107 15:12:28.746661  6410 registrar.cpp:479] Successfully updated 'registry'
I0107 15:12:28.746722  6414 log.cpp:699] Attempting to truncate the log to 849
I0107 15:12:28.746759  6409 master.cpp:2851] Registered slave 20150107-150547-406956224-
5050-6393-32 at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72)
I0107 15:12:28.746775  6410 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write TRUNCATE 
action at position 850
I0107 15:12:28.746789  6409 master.cpp:4085] Adding slave 20150107-150547-406956224-5050-
6393-32 at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72) with cpus(*):4; 
mem(*):6785; disk(*):144943; ports(*):[31000-32000]
I0107 15:12:28.746940  6407 replica.cpp:508] Replica received write request for position 
850
I0107 15:12:28.746958  6409 master.cpp:775] Slave 20150107-150547-406956224-5050-6393-32 
at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72) disconnected
I0107 15:12:28.746968  6409 master.cpp:1680] Disconnecting slave 20150107-150547-
406956224-5050-6393-32
I0107 15:12:28.746999  6409 hierarchical_allocator_process.hpp:442] Added slave 20150107- 
150547-406956224-5050-6393-32 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72) with cpus(*):4; 
mem(*):6785; disk(*):144943; ports(*):[31000-32000] (and cpus(*):4; mem(*):6785; 
disk(*):144943; ports(*):[31000-32000] available)
I0107 15:12:28.747051  6409 hierarchical_allocator_process.hpp:481] Slave 20150107-
150547-406956224-5050-6393-32 deactivated
I0107 15:12:28.788100  6407 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (18 bytes) to leveldb took 
41.139421ms
I0107 15:12:28.788164  6407 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 850
I0107 15:12:28.788331  6411 replica.cpp:655] Replica received learned notice for position 
850
I0107 15:12:28.829857  6411 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (20 bytes) to leveldb took 
41.48648ms
I0107 15:12:28.829910  6411 leveldb.cpp:401] Deleting ~2 keys from leveldb took 23122ns
I0107 15:12:28.829924  6411 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 850
I0107 15:12:28.829936  6411 replica.cpp:661] Replica learned TRUNCATE action at position 
850
I0107 15:12:29.070030  6412 master.cpp:2781] Removing old disconnected slave 20150107-
150547-406956224-5050-6393-32 at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-
Edge72) because a registration attempt is being made from slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051
I0107 15:12:29.070081  6412 master.cpp:4218] Removing slave 20150107-150547-406956224-
5050-6393-32 at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72)
I0107 15:12:29.070184  6407 hierarchical_allocator_process.hpp:467] Removed slave 
20150107-150547-406956224-5050-6393-32
I0107 15:12:29.070305  6412 master.cpp:2811] Registering slave at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 
(mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72) with id 20150107-150547-406956224-5050-6393-33
I0107 15:12:29.070363  6411 registrar.cpp:422] Attempting to update the 'registry'
I0107 15:12:29.071686  6412 log.cpp:680] Attempting to append 344 bytes to the log
I0107 15:12:29.071750  6414 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write APPEND 
action at position 851
I0107 15:12:29.072064  6408 replica.cpp:508] Replica received write request for position 
851
I0107 15:12:29.104596  6408 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (364 bytes) to leveldb 
took 32.50025ms
I0107 15:12:29.104645  6408 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 851
I0107 15:12:29.104837  6409 replica.cpp:655] Replica received learned notice for position 
851
I0107 15:12:29.146327  6409 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (366 bytes) to leveldb 
took 41.451476ms
I0107 15:12:29.146374  6409 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 851
I0107 15:12:29.146390  6409 replica.cpp:661] Replica learned APPEND action at position  
851
I0107 15:12:29.146685  6409 registrar.cpp:479] Successfully updated 'registry'
I0107 15:12:29.146765  6412 log.cpp:699] Attempting to truncate the log to 851
I0107 15:12:29.146781  6409 registrar.cpp:422] Attempting to update the 'registry'
I0107 15:12:29.146823  6407 master.cpp:4321] Removed slave 20150107-150547-406956224-
5050-6393-32 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72)
I0107 15:12:29.146837  6411 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write TRUNCATE 
action at position 852
I0107 15:12:29.147100  6414 replica.cpp:508] Replica received write request for position 
852
I0107 15:12:29.188091  6414 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (18 bytes) to leveldb took 
40.960719ms
I0107 15:12:29.188145  6414 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 852
I0107 15:12:29.188280  6414 replica.cpp:655] Replica received learned notice for position 
852
I0107 15:12:29.229823  6414 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (20 bytes) to leveldb took 
41.531512ms
I0107 15:12:29.229907  6414 leveldb.cpp:401] Deleting ~2 keys from leveldb took 30444ns
I0107 15:12:29.229926  6414 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 852
I0107 15:12:29.229939  6414 replica.cpp:661] Replica learned TRUNCATE action at position 
852
I0107 15:12:29.230134  6410 log.cpp:680] Attempting to append 550 bytes to the log
I0107 15:12:29.230185  6410 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write APPEND 
action at position 853
I0107 15:12:29.230376  6411 replica.cpp:508] Replica received write request for position 
853
I0107 15:12:29.271564  6411 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (570 bytes) to leveldb 
took 41.128758ms
I0107 15:12:29.271617  6411 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 853
I0107 15:12:29.271826  6411 replica.cpp:655] Replica received learned notice for position 
853
I0107 15:12:29.313411  6411 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (572 bytes) to leveldb 
took 41.551225ms
I0107 15:12:29.313457  6411 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 853
I0107 15:12:29.313473  6411 replica.cpp:661] Replica learned APPEND action at position 
853
I0107 15:12:29.313753  6410 registrar.cpp:479] Successfully updated 'registry'
I0107 15:12:29.313794  6409 log.cpp:699] Attempting to truncate the log to 853
I0107 15:12:29.313823  6413 master.cpp:2851] Registered slave 20150107-150547-406956224-
5050-6393-33 at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72)
I0107 15:12:29.313843  6413 master.cpp:4085] Adding slave 20150107-150547-406956224-5050-
6393-33 at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72) with cpus(*):4; 
mem(*):6785; disk(*):144943; ports(*):[31000-32000]
I0107 15:12:29.313854  6410 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write TRUNCATE 
action at position 854
I0107 15:12:29.314043  6409 replica.cpp:508] Replica received write request for position 
854
I0107 15:12:29.314091  6413 master.cpp:775] Slave 20150107-150547-406956224-5050-6393-33 
at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72) disconnected
I0107 15:12:29.314115  6413 master.cpp:1680] Disconnecting slave 20150107-150547-
406956224-5050-6393-33
I0107 15:12:29.314128  6410 hierarchical_allocator_process.hpp:442] Added slave 20150107-
150547-406956224-5050-6393-33 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72) with cpus(*):4; 
mem(*):6785; disk(*):144943; ports(*):[31000-32000] (and cpus(*):4; mem(*):6785; 
disk(*):144943; ports(*):[31000-32000] available)
I0107 15:12:29.314184  6410 hierarchical_allocator_process.hpp:481] Slave 20150107-
150547-406956224-5050-6393-33 deactivated
I0107 15:12:29.355125  6409 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (18 bytes) to leveldb took 
41.039775ms
I0107 15:12:29.355178  6409 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 854
I0107 15:12:29.355316  6409 replica.cpp:655] Replica received learned notice for position 
854
I0107 15:12:29.396852  6409 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (20 bytes) to leveldb took 
41.50737ms
I0107 15:12:29.396934  6409 leveldb.cpp:401] Deleting ~2 keys from leveldb took 30887ns
I0107 15:12:29.396955  6409 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 854
I0107 15:12:29.396967  6409 replica.cpp:661] Replica learned TRUNCATE action at position 
854
I0107 15:12:29.529793  6407 master.cpp:2781] Removing old disconnected slave 20150107-
150547-406956224-5050-6393-33 at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-
Edge72) because a registration attempt is being made from slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051
I0107 15:12:29.529831  6407 master.cpp:4218] Removing slave 20150107-150547-406956224-
5050-6393-33 at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72)
I0107 15:12:29.529917  6414 hierarchical_allocator_process.hpp:467] Removed slave 
20150107-150547-406956224-5050-6393-33
I0107 15:12:29.529963  6407 master.cpp:2811] Registering slave at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 
(mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72) with id 20150107-150547-406956224-5050-6393-34
I0107 15:12:29.529988  6412 registrar.cpp:422] Attempting to update the 'registry'
I0107 15:12:29.531298  6410 log.cpp:680] Attempting to append 344 bytes to the log
I0107 15:12:29.531371  6410 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write APPEND 
action at position 855
I0107 15:12:29.531597  6411 replica.cpp:508] Replica received write request for position 
855
I0107 15:12:29.571789  6411 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (364 bytes) to leveldb 
took 40.154081ms
I0107 15:12:29.571836  6411 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 855
I0107 15:12:29.572059  6412 replica.cpp:655] Replica received learned notice for position 
855
I0107 15:12:29.613510  6412 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (366 bytes) to leveldb 
took 41.426794ms
I0107 15:12:29.613565  6412 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 855
I0107 15:12:29.613584  6412 replica.cpp:661] Replica learned APPEND action at position 
855
I0107 15:12:29.613906  6414 registrar.cpp:479] Successfully updated 'registry'
I0107 15:12:29.613915  6412 log.cpp:699] Attempting to truncate the log to 855
I0107 15:12:29.613998  6407 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write TRUNCATE 
action at position 856
I0107 15:12:29.614168  6407 replica.cpp:508] Replica received write request for position 
856
I0107 15:12:29.613999  6414 registrar.cpp:422] Attempting to update the 'registry'
I0107 15:12:29.614001  6412 master.cpp:4321] Removed slave 20150107-150547-406956224-
5050-6393-33 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72)
I0107 15:12:29.655239  6407 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (18 bytes) to leveldb took 
41.046542ms
I0107 15:12:29.655294  6407 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 856
I0107 15:12:29.655437  6407 replica.cpp:655] Replica received learned notice for position 
856
I0107 15:12:29.696975  6407 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (20 bytes) to leveldb took 
41.51733ms
I0107 15:12:29.697057  6407 leveldb.cpp:401] Deleting ~2 keys from leveldb took 30767ns
I0107 15:12:29.697078  6407 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 856
I0107 15:12:29.697090  6407 replica.cpp:661] Replica learned TRUNCATE action at position 
856
I0107 15:12:29.697302  6414 log.cpp:680] Attempting to append 550 bytes to the log
I0107 15:12:29.697357  6412 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write APPEND 
action at position 857
I0107 15:12:29.697630  6409 replica.cpp:508] Replica received write request for position 
857
I0107 15:12:29.738620  6409 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (570 bytes) to leveldb 
took 40.971859ms
I0107 15:12:29.738662  6409 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 857
I0107 15:12:29.738785  6409 replica.cpp:655] Replica received learned notice for position 
857
I0107 15:12:29.780450  6409 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (572 bytes) to leveldb 
took 41.637468ms
I0107 15:12:29.780506  6409 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 857
I0107 15:12:29.780524  6409 replica.cpp:661] Replica learned APPEND action at position 
857
I0107 15:12:29.780766  6409 registrar.cpp:479] Successfully updated 'registry'
I0107 15:12:29.780788  6410 log.cpp:699] Attempting to truncate the log to 857
I0107 15:12:29.780823  6413 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write TRUNCATE 
action at position 858
I0107 15:12:29.780838  6412 master.cpp:2851] Registered slave 20150107-150547-406956224-
5050-6393-34 at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72)
I0107 15:12:29.780858  6412 master.cpp:4085] Adding slave 20150107-150547-406956224-5050-
6393-34 at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72) with cpus(*):4; 
mem(*):6785; disk(*):144943; ports(*):[31000-32000]
I0107 15:12:29.780977  6410 replica.cpp:508] Replica received write request for position 
858
I0107 15:12:29.780987  6412 master.cpp:775] Slave 20150107-150547-406956224-5050-6393-34 
at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72) disconnected
I0107 15:12:29.780997  6412 master.cpp:1680] Disconnecting slave 20150107-150547-
406956224-5050-6393-34
I0107 15:12:29.781045  6414 hierarchical_allocator_process.hpp:442] Added slave 20150107-
150547-406956224-5050-6393-34 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72) with cpus(*):4; 
mem(*):6785; disk(*):144943; ports(*):[31000-32000] (and cpus(*):4; mem(*):6785; 
disk(*):144943; ports(*):[31000-32000] available)
I0107 15:12:29.781128  6414 hierarchical_allocator_process.hpp:481] Slave 20150107-
150547-406956224-5050-6393-34 deactivated
I0107 15:12:29.822186  6410 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (18 bytes) to leveldb took 
41.194886ms
I0107 15:12:29.822240  6410 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 858
I0107 15:12:29.822494  6407 replica.cpp:655] Replica received learned notice for position 
858
I0107 15:12:29.863934  6407 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (20 bytes) to leveldb took 
41.397501ms
I0107 15:12:29.863970  6407 leveldb.cpp:401] Deleting ~2 keys from leveldb took 14397ns
I0107 15:12:29.863980  6407 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 858
I0107 15:12:29.863987  6407 replica.cpp:661] Replica learned TRUNCATE action at position 
858
I0107 15:12:30.644934  6413 http.cpp:466] HTTP request for '/master/state.json'
I0107 15:12:36.460794  6408 master.cpp:2781] Removing old disconnected slave 20150107-
150547-406956224-5050-6393-34 at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-
Edge72) because a registration attempt is being made from slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051

I0107 15:12:36.460850  6408 master.cpp:4218] Removing slave 20150107-150547-406956224-
5050-6393-34 at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72)
I0107 15:12:36.460953  6407 hierarchical_allocator_process.hpp:467] Removed slave 
20150107- 150547-406956224-5050-6393-34
I0107 15:12:36.461001  6408 master.cpp:2811] Registering slave at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 
(mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72) with id 20150107-150547-406956224-5050-6393-35
I0107 15:12:36.461027  6407 registrar.cpp:422] Attempting to update the 'registry'
I0107 15:12:36.461735  6409 log.cpp:680] Attempting to append 344 bytes to the log
I0107 15:12:36.461803  6408 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write APPEND 
action at position 859
I0107 15:12:36.462061  6414 replica.cpp:508] Replica received write request for position 
859
I0107 15:12:36.479645  6414 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (364 bytes) to leveldb 
took 17.545233ms
I0107 15:12:36.479693  6414 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 859
I0107 15:12:36.479923  6414 replica.cpp:655] Replica received learned notice for position 
859
I0107 15:12:36.515755  6414 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (366 bytes) to leveldb 
took 35.807609ms
I0107 15:12:36.515801  6414 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 859
I0107 15:12:36.515818  6414 replica.cpp:661] Replica learned APPEND action at position 
859
I0107 15:12:36.516130  6414 registrar.cpp:479] Successfully updated 'registry'
I0107 15:12:36.516180  6407 log.cpp:699] Attempting to truncate the log to 859
I0107 15:12:36.516222  6414 registrar.cpp:422] Attempting to update the 'registry'
I0107 15:12:36.516242  6407 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write TRUNCATE 
action at position 860
I0107 15:12:36.516243  6410 master.cpp:4321] Removed slave 20150107-150547-406956224-
5050-6393-34 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72)
I0107 15:12:36.516499  6411 replica.cpp:508] Replica received write request for position 
860
I0107 15:12:36.557504  6411 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (18 bytes) to leveldb took 
40.974358ms
I0107 15:12:36.557559  6411 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 860
I0107 15:12:36.557689  6412 replica.cpp:655] Replica received learned notice for position 
860
I0107 15:12:36.599247  6412 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (20 bytes) to leveldb took 
41.522371ms
I0107 15:12:36.599334  6412 leveldb.cpp:401] Deleting ~2 keys from leveldb took 32551ns
I0107 15:12:36.599354  6412 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 860
I0107 15:12:36.599367  6412 replica.cpp:661] Replica learned TRUNCATE action at position 
860
I0107 15:12:36.599599  6409 log.cpp:680] Attempting to append 550 bytes to the log
I0107 15:12:36.599660  6409 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write APPEND 
action at position 861
I0107 15:12:36.599859  6409 replica.cpp:508] Replica received write request for position 
861
I0107 15:12:36.641084  6409 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (570 bytes) to leveldb 
took 41.195477ms
I0107 15:12:36.641137  6409 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 861
I0107 15:12:36.641297  6409 replica.cpp:655] Replica received learned notice for position 
861
I0107 15:12:36.682837  6409 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (572 bytes) to leveldb 
took 41.528099ms
I0107 15:12:36.682858  6409 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 861
I0107 15:12:36.682868  6409 replica.cpp:661] Replica learned APPEND action at position 
861
I0107 15:12:36.683104  6409 registrar.cpp:479] Successfully updated 'registry'
I0107 15:12:36.683161  6410 log.cpp:699] Attempting to truncate the log to 861
I0107 15:12:36.683189  6410 coordinator.cpp:340] Coordinator attempting to write TRUNCATE 
action at position 862
I0107 15:12:36.683195  6414 master.cpp:2851] Registered slave 20150107-150547-406956224-
5050-6393-35 at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72)
I0107 15:12:36.683213  6414 master.cpp:4085] Adding slave 20150107-150547-406956224-5050-
6393-35 at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72) with cpus(*):4; 
mem(*):6785; disk(*):144943; ports(*):[31000-32000]
I0107 15:12:36.683306  6407 replica.cpp:508] Replica received write request for position 
862
I0107 15:12:36.683346  6414 master.cpp:775] Slave 20150107-150547-406956224-5050-6393-35 
at slave(1)@127.0.1.1:5051 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72) disconnected
I0107 15:12:36.683368  6414 master.cpp:1680] Disconnecting slave 20150107-150547-
406956224-5050-6393-35
I0107 15:12:36.683452  6412 hierarchical_allocator_process.hpp:442] Added slave 20150107-
150547-406956224-5050-6393-35 (mesos_slave1-ThinkCentre-Edge72) with cpus(*):4; 
mem(*):6785; disk(*):144943; ports(*):[31000-32000] (and cpus(*):4; mem(*):6785; 
disk(*):144943; ports(*):[31000-32000] available)
I0107 15:12:36.683516  6412 hierarchical_allocator_process.hpp:481] Slave 20150107-
150547-406956224-5050-6393-35 deactivated
I0107 15:12:36.724563  6407 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (18 bytes) to leveldb took 
41.207139ms
I0107 15:12:36.724611  6407 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 862
I0107 15:12:36.724793  6408 replica.cpp:655] Replica received learned notice for position 
862
I0107 15:12:36.766309  6408 leveldb.cpp:343] Persisting action (20 bytes) to leveldb took 
41.490591ms
I0107 15:12:36.766386  6408 leveldb.cpp:401] Deleting ~2 keys from leveldb took 30472ns
I0107 15:12:36.766405  6408 replica.cpp:676] Persisted action at 862
I0107 15:12:36.766417  6408 replica.cpp:661] Replica learned TRUNCATE action at position 
862
I0107 15:12:40.659693  6413 http.cpp:466] HTTP request for '/master/state.json'
```

I tried running mesos-master.sh on a different machine and tried connecting slaves from  other machines but the output  is the same. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like the slaves are trying to register as `127.0.1.1:5051`, so only 1 slave can be registered at that that hostname:port. There are at least two ways to fix this:

- Set `--ip=<non-localhost-ip>` when launching mesos-slave
- Modify `/etc/hosts` on each slave such that `hostname` resolves to something other than `127.0.x.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Install `mesosphere`. You can get the the instructions [here](https://mesosphere.com/docs/tutorials/install_ubuntu_debian/). After installation run `mesos-master` on master and `mesos-slave` on slaves with ip that point to your master. If you get `port already used error` as mentioned by Adam above, try running slave on a different port using argument `--port=value`. If you get permission denied while running on another port try sudo.

Comment: Mesosphere packages are are working fine for me. @Adam on the same scenario mesos list recently connected slaves. Sometimes it lists all the slaves but after a while (~2 minutes) some slaves get disconnected automatically.